# Why HMM transition probabilities plays no significant role in speech modeling

Tags: audio-processing, speech-processing, hmm

I'm reading a [thesis](https://www.fit.vut.cz/study/phd-thesis/751/.en), it mainly uses a GMM-HMM to tackle the acoustic unit discovery task. It proposes a delicate Bayesian framework on top of the GMM-HMM. In page 15 it says

> Notice that we have not included any parameters of the transition probabilities as it has been empirically observed that they play no significant role when modeling speech (Bourlard, 1996). **Consequently, we assume the transition probabilities are fixed parameters such that the probability to go to any state given the current state is the same.**

I guess the claim is something general (so the Bayesian things won't matter much). However, the reference (Bourlard, 1996) seems to be an old French literature that I cannot access. Can someone explain briefly why it's true or point me somewhere that is accessible?

Thank you in advance.